# React redux routing with hot reloading does not work with refresh

Tags: reactjs, routes, redux, webpack-dev-server

I have the following routes defined

```
<Route path='/' component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={LoginContainer} />
        <Route path='landing' component={LandingComponent} />
        <Route path='login' component={LoginContainer} />
    </Route>
```

Now when the user clicks a login button on the loginContainer he is directed to the landing page (from the routes /landing).  So now the url changes to 
http://server:port/landing

Now if I modify a file and save with hot module reloading (web pack dev server) I get an error saying cannot get http://server:port/landing.  This is true because there is no such page, how do I fix this problem.

I am using react-router, react-router-redux, and webpack dev server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#the-historyapifallback-option) in your webpack dev server config.

This will redirect to the index page on a 404 and consequently allow the router to kick in to find your subroute.

For more info for why this is necessary, or some other, more indepth wy around it, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/6902543).